# Why is my H2 database Spring config not working?

Tags: spring, h2

I am always getting java.lang.**NoSuchMethodError**: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager$JpaTransactionObject.setReadOnly(Z)V

I do not know why.

I use H2 database in memory. According to spring there is no configuration necessary. I just include the dependency in my maven POM . But when I call the database it gives me this error.

```
public interface ClientRepository extends CrudRepository<Client, Long> {
```

I know a lot had this error before but I cannot see any mistake on my side. According to spring it should work out of the box. Just add maven dependency. Nothing more. So where is my error.

It seems that if you mix Spring boot dependencies and Spring framework dependencies maybe this could cause a problem. I really do not know. I removed this dependency

```
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
       <version>5.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

It was not Spring boot . So I would not need it anyway. I think Spring boot will never ever need any Spring framework dependency I guess.

Also versions could maybe be an issue. I did not include any version. Because Spring boot should then just take the latest one. Right ? But now I have versions. Maybe this was also an issue.

Comment: I just adjusted my POM.xml . And now it seems to work in terms of no more noSuchMethodError. It is really annoying. You really have to make sure you use the right versions and the right jars etc.

Comment: No you don't. That's what spring starter poms are for. Furthermore, I do not see in your post that you have the h2 driver on your classpath. This is also necessary together with your url, username and password in application.properties, once you have these things you should be good to go.